# $("input").val(); does not return value if it is outside the function

Tags: function, scope

```
<input id="tel" type="text" placeholder="input" /><br><br>
<button>Check</button>
```

This code not works

```
let myTel = $("#tel").val();
$('button').click(function(){  
    console.log(myTel);  
});
```

This code works

```
$('button').click(function(){ 
    let myTel = $("#tel").val(); 
    console.log(myTel);  
});
```

What can I do, when I am going to declare the variable myTel outside the function

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/6wkqnxL5/

Comment: Code outside any function runs when the script is first loaded, therefore, it'll only get the default value of the control, most likely empty. The second example finds the value at every time the button is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

because in uper case when `let myTel = $("#tel").val();` loads input got no vlaue so empty let and on event triger callback shows smae value fron let.

in second case when event triggers it get value in that instence of time so gets the actual input filled value out of it.

you can do this

```
let myTel=null;
$('button').click(function(){ 
   myTel= $("#tel").val(); 
   console.log(myTel);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the variable undefined at the top.
And when the user clicks the button, the **myTel** variable is going to be assigned with the value of the input field.

```
let myTel;
$('button').click(function(){  
  myTel = $("#tel").val();
  console.log(myTel);  
});
```